# How to connect fonts on the page globaly?

Tags: html, css, fonts

There are two ways to do that:

- Using link in meta tags HTML
- Add fonts directly in CSS file

I have some files like as: `CRC35.otf`

How to do that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Best way is to use google fonts
http://fonts.google.com
you can import it meta tag like this  (to use eg. Noto Sans Font)

```
`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans" rel="stylesheet">`
```

or directly to css

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans');
```

and use it as

```
{
font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

:)

Answer (score 1):

Use the .otf file and convert to other font formats with this tool https://transfonter.org/ and then embedd them all in CSS file like this

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'CRC35';
src: url('CRC35.eot');
src: url('CRC35.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('CRC35.woff') format('woff'),
    url('CRC35.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

Comment: Need I specify here extention .otf : font-family: 'CRC35';?

Comment: No. That name you will be using trough the rest of CSS code that will point to the the font files. It can be whatever you wish. But the font files declaration (src) with extensions have to be pointed to real files and with full path to them.

Comment: So, path I dont need  specify too?

Comment: In the `font-family: 'CRC35';` declaration no path, only name you want to use for that font. The name can be anything and you will need it for seting that font in rest of css. If you use "CRC35" name later in css for example it should be `body { font-family: "CRC35"; }`

Comment: Problem is that I use webpack for Angular 2, and when I added this fons to CSS file Webpack did not compilte that